# Assume $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, what is the sufficient condition on eigenvalues and eigenvectors in order that $A$ is hermitian?

Tags: matrices

Assume $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, what is the sufficient condition on eigenvalues and eigenvectors in order that $A$ is hermitian?

I can only know the necessary condition. But struggle with the sufficient condition.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ has distinct eigenvalues there is a basis $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ consisting of eigenvectors: $$Ae_i=\lambda_i e_i\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$ If $A=A'$ then for all $i$, $k$ the following is valid:
$$\lambda_i\langle e_i,e_k\rangle=\langle \lambda_i e_i,e_k\rangle=\langle Ae_i,e_k\rangle=\langle e_i, A e_k\rangle=\langle  e_i,\lambda_k e_k\rangle=\bar\lambda _k\langle  e_i,e_k\rangle\ .\tag{1}$$
Putting $k=i$ here and noting that $\langle e_i, e_i\rangle>0$ we can conclude that $\lambda_i\in{\mathbb R}$ for all $i$. When $i\ne k$ then $(1)$ implies that $e_i\perp e_k$.

The conditions we found are also sufficient: If we have an orthogonal basis consisting of eigenvectors we can normalize them and obtain an orthonormal basis. The transformation $A$ then has a real diagonal matrix with respect to this basis, whence is hermitian.

Comment: Why eigenvectors of hermitian matrix have to be normalized?

Comment: @Elessarr They don't have to be, it's just convenient to have $V^* V = I$ when proving the last step in the answer above. Without it you have an additional couple constants to move around at the end.